# SFDX: Move from Changeset Deployment to Org Development Model

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, mdapideploy

I'm planning to move from changeset Deployment approach to org development model which can provide more flexible and scalable environment for development. Also it can provide source tracking in version control system such as GitHub. When I download the metadata from my production org and zip the folder, I try to deploy the zip folder to a sandbox with command `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`, however, many errors prop out.

Most errors are related to the objects in managed packages are not found and namespace in those packages cannot recognize. I have purchased and installed several managed packages and I've used some of the objects in those packages in my own trigger. So how could I include those managed packages in the metadata that I used to deploy to a sandbox to make the org development model success?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify dependencies, as demonstrated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_config_file.htm).

You can use `force:package:installed:list` to get the ID values for dependencies that you need to specify. This is primarily intended for Unlocked Packages, which will eventually be your path forward.

You can also use [Org-Dependent Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_org_dependent.htm), which will include dependencies in your org automatically.